# On the non-separability of $\ell^\infty$: definition of a one-to-one function.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

[image]

We denote with $A$ the set of all sequence $y$ of this type.

> My doubt concerns the definition of a one-to-one function between the set $A$ and the real numbers of $[0,1]$ which have that binary representation.

We define $$f\colon A\to [0,1],\qquad y=(\eta_1,\eta_2\,\cdots)\mapsto \hat{y}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\eta_k}{2^k}$$

It's clear that when Kreyszig says: "each $\hat{y}\in [0,1]$ has a binary representation" means that this function is surjective.

When Kreyszig says: "different $\hat{y}$' have different binary representation", what does it mean? I can't get the injectivity out of this sentence. Could you give me some suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: The sequences $(1,0,\ldots,0,\ldots )$ and $(0,1,\ldots, 1,\ldots )$ give the same result $\widehat{y}={1\over 2}.$ The mapping $y\mapsto \widehat{y}$ is surjective but not injective. If we restrict to the elements in $\ell^\infty$ which contain infinitely many $1,$ then the mapping $y\mapsto \widehat{y}$ will be bijective onto $(0,1].$ By the way the zero-one sequences can be identified with the family of all subsets of $\mathbb{N}.$ Therefore the cardinality of this family is equal continuum, which is uncountable. There is no need to use the interval $[0,1].$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Thanks, I would like to understand exactly why Kreyszig proceeds this way.

Comment: Who knows ? In my opinion it is easier to show that the family of zero-one sequences is uncountable, without referring to the interval $[0,1].$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc But apparently Kreyszig uses interval $[0,1]$ and I don't like to change book proofs. Thank you so much for your interest.

Comment: Actually the Kreyszig reasoning is a circular argument. In order to show that $[0,1]$ is uncountable the binary (or decimal) representations of numbers are applied, so we go back to zero-one sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Two different sequences can correspond to the same real number:
$$
\frac{1}{2^1}+\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{0}{2^j}
=\frac{1}{2} =
\frac{0}{2^1}+\sum_{j=2}^\infty\frac{1}{2^j}
$$
A slight error.  Indeed, one which Cantor made long ago.  But correct variants were soon provided.  For example, there is no surjective map from a countable set onto $[0,1]$.  The map here is surjective.  Therefore the set $A$ of $\{0,1\}$ sequences in $l^\infty$ is not countable.

[The proof then goes on to show $A$ is not separable, and therefore $l^\infty$ is not separable.]

Comment: Thanks. Now, if we know that the map is surjective can we conclude on the cardinality of $A$?

Comment: I should add that, yes.